# jquery: Getting 'src' from data-url and add the same

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JavaScript, jQuery and Stack.

I'm trying to get the url with `data().url` and add the same as `src` to each `img`. Here is an example of the HTML.

```
<ol>
  <li><div class="image"><img data-url="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/.../s400/image-1.png"/></div></li>
  <li><div class="image"><img data-url="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/.../s400/image-2.png"/></div></li>
  <li><div class="image"><img data-url="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/.../s400/image-3.png"/></div></li>
</ol>
```

How this can be achieved with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".image img").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("src" , $(this).data().url );
});
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/42A93/1/

Welcome to SO!

Comment: Oh... my bad, I was doing it wrong for `var` while changing the size of the image. However, thank you all for the help... and @Cherniv, it worked perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
$('.image img').attr('src', function(){ return $(this).data('url') });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".image img").attr('src', function(){
    return $(this).data('url');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.image img' ).map( function(){
     this.setAttribute('src', this.getAttribute('data-url'));
});
```